# why is "test-jar" dependency required for "mvn compile"

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

I'm having trouble using `test-jar` dependencies in a multi-module project. For example, when I declare that the `cleartk-syntax` module depends on the `cleartk-token` module's `test-jar` like this (the full code is [here](https://cleartk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.cleartk</groupId>
<artifactId>cleartk-syntax</artifactId>
<version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cleartk-syntax</name>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cleartk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cleartk-token</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I get the following error if I run `mvn compile` using maven 2:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) org.cleartk:cleartk-token:test-jar:tests:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If I use maven 3 I get the error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.654s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 24 21:19:17 CET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cleartk-syntax: Could not resolve
dependencies for project org.cleartk:cleartk-syntax:jar:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could
not find artifact org.cleartk:cleartk-token:jar:tests:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
```

In the latter case, I'm particularly confused because I would have thought it should be looking for an artifact of type `test-jar` not of type `jar`.

With maven 2 or maven 3, I can get it to compile by running `mvn compile package -DskipTests`. With maven 3, I can also get it to compile by running `mvn compile test-compile`.

But why is either maven 2 or maven 3 looking for a `test-jar` dependency during the `compile` phase? Shouldn't it wait until the `test-compile` phase to look for such dependencies?

**Update:** The answer was that the maven-exec-plugin, used during my compile phase, [requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope:test](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html). I've created [a feature request to remove the scope:test dependency](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-91).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a definite bug to me.

I have the same problem and tested Maven 3.0.1 and 3.0.2. Validate doesn't fail, only the compile step fails. With Maven 3 `mvn compile` breaks but `mvn test-compile` works.

It appears that the compile phase is looking for test-jar artifacts in the reactor and then repo, but it shouldn't since the dependency is in test scope. Test scope artifacts should be resolved during test-compile, not compile.

As a result, I thought this could be worked around by mapping the maven-compiler-plugin's testCompile goal to the compile phase, instead of the default test-compile phase.

I added this to my pom, right next to the part that adds the test-jar creation in the upstream pom:

```
  <!-- there is a bug in maven causing it to resolve test-jar types
       at compile time rather than test-compile. Move the compilation 
       of the test classes earlier in the build cycle -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-testCompile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But that won't work either because the five phases between compile and test-compile haven't run and set up things like the test classpath.

I guess the real workaround until this bug is fixed is to use `test-compile` in place of `compile`.

Comment: I have confirmed that the first maven phase to work is test-compile.  process-test-resources fails.

Comment: Glad to hear that I'm not alone in running into this bug. In your case are you also using the `exec:java` plugin - that seemed to be part of the problem for me. If not, are you binding any other plugins to execution phases?

Comment: What I've recently discovered, but have not yet unwound, is that I can cause the problem with a very reduced set of 3 pom files.  If these three (my project) inherit from nothing, it works.  If they inherit from org.apache:apache it breaks.  So one of the plugins defined there is probably breaking it.  There is no exec:java plugin there -- but one of those plugins and the exec one probably depend on something else broken upstream.  I'll comment here if I can narrow it down.

Comment: In my case, the issue is in maven-remote-resources.  I filed http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRRESOURCES-53.   If anyone else has this problem and it is not due to exec:java, this might be it.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it says it was active 12 days ago. Can someone look at my comment on the Maven bug that @Steve posted? None of the workarounds mentioned in this post work for me. Not being able to package my project is kind of a deal-breaker for me... http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-91?focusedCommentId=318104#comment-318104

Comment: I had this problem also.  This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722873/sharing-src-test-classes-between-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project

Answer (score 16):

In my case the root cause was that the module which should be used as a dependency in `test` scope with type `test-jar` did not include the required `maven-jar-plugin` configuration. Without the snippet below no test jar will be deployed when you call `mvn deploy` on the respective module.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html for more details.

Comment: That was my root cause, too.

Answer (score 2):

So I did some serious debugging, and discovered that the problem seems to be an interaction between the `exec:java` plugin, `test-jar` dependencies and `mvn compile`.

In short, if you attach `exec:java` to an execution phase, `mvn compile` starts looking for `test-jar` dependencies at compile time. If you remove the `<executions>` element from the `exec:java` plugin declaration, `mvn compile` works fine again.

I filed a bug report for the `exec:java` plugin here, though I can't really tell whether the bug is in `exec:java`, `test-jar` or `mvn compile` so perhaps the bug will be moved somewhere else if/when someone figures that out:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-91

**Update:** It's not really a bug, the maven-exec-plugin is documented as requiring test dependencies here:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html

That doesn't mean it wouldn't make a great feature. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am using maven2. I guess the answer is in the maven lifecycle management.
The first step of a default lifecycle is validate, which does 'validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available.' (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html ).

So maven just tries its best to get all the needed dependencies for the later execution.

Comment: But if that's the case, then why does `mvn compile package` work?

Comment: You've mentioned that it only works if you provide -DskipTests=true variable. Can that be something of internal optimization of maven?

Comment: It works without -DskipTests too. I just added that since I'm only trying to compile, not to test.