# Sharing src/test classes between modules in a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a multi-module Maven project.  For the sake of this example, consider two modules:

- `data`
- `consumer`

Module `consumer` has module `data` as a dependency.

Module `data` declares a bunch of core classes.  There are tests under `src/test` that use them.  These tests require some long-winded object creation, so I have a class with some utility methods in it to create these objects.  This utility class (`SampleDataHelper`) is in the `src/test` hierarchy.

I also have some tests in the `consumer` module that need to create some of these long-winded objects.  I want to use my `SampleDataHelper` class (defined in `data src/test`) in tests that reside in my `consumer src/test` tree.  Unfortunately, even though `data` is a dependency of `consumer`, `consumer` can't see the classes that exist under `data src/test`.

To combat this, I thought I might create *another* module (`data-test`), and move `SampleDataHelper` to it under **`src/main`**.  Then I would include `data-test` as a *test scope* dependency of `data`.  Unfortunately, this introduces a circular dependency: `data` uses `data-test`, but `data-test` also requires `data`.

The only solution I've come up with is to place `SampleDataHelper` under `data src/main` under a `test` package and hope that no real application code ever calls it.

How can I share my `SampleDataHelper` class between modules *without* putting it under `src/main`?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733745/966590). I think it should help you.

Comment: For future readers: [Maven Guide to using attached tests](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html)

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: wouldn't your linked answer require a "two-step" build? To first build and *deploy* one module (`data`) before I can even compile my second module (`consumer`).

Comment: I think you _might_ come across some problems if you use `mvn package`, but it should work just fine in a single step build when you use `mvn install` or `mvn deploy`. Just a quick note. In one of our large projects we have a wrapper over junit's `TestBase` and it's located in `src/main` which I don't consider to be a good idea either.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Your Consumer project depends upon your Data project, therefore we are happy that Data must be built prior to Consumer. As a result, using the techniques suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722873/sharing-src-test-classes-between-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project#comment20596777_14722873), I would ensure your Data project contains all the test code that you wish to share and configure the POM to produce a test JAR:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Your Consumer project would then depend upon both the normal Data JAR artifact, plus the additional `test-jar` artifact, with test scope of course:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>data</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've used this approach on many occasions and it works well.

Comment: regarding "Your Consumer project would then depend upon both the normal Data JAR artifact, plus the additional test-jar artifact" part, when I adding both the dependencies of data into consumer (let's say my artifacts named data & consumer as well) pom, without specific versions specification, the pom got error. Why is that happen?

Comment: @StasS probably best you open a separate question about that.

Comment: Did it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119591/sharing-src-test-classes-with-maven-without-version-specification-for-test-jar

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that (some) tests in the `data` module depend on the `SampleDataHelper` class? You can move the `SampleDataHelper` class to `src/main` of the `data-test` module, if you at the same time move the tests (that depend on the specific class) to the `src/test` of the `data-test` module. Consequently, there would be no more circular dependencies.

Comment: If I understand you, you're suggesting that any tests that use `SampleDataHelper` be moved from either the `data` module or the `consumer` module (as appropriate) into `data-test`.  Unfortunately I don't find this a very "neat" solution as it moves my tests out of the module they test, and into a different one. (Strictly speaking, you only said to move the `data` tests, but I think I'd find myself moving both for consistency).  But thank you for your answer. :-)

Comment: Yep, you understood me correctly. And arguably, it's more of a quick solution than a neat one. :-)

Comment: I would imagine the circular dependencies would remain. Assuming that the tests in question exercise the classes defined in the Data project, there would still need to be a reference back to the Data project from the Data-Test project.

Comment: @DuncanJones Sorry, there was a small typo in my post. The point I'm trying to make is that the `data-test` module should depend on the `data` module (and not the other way around). To avoid the circular dependency, all tests that currently reside in the `data` module that uses the `SampleDataHelper` must be moved to the `data-test` module.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense.