# Maven can not find test superclass from different module

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 modules mod1 and mod2 from a same parent project.
mod2 depends on mod1 and mod2 pom.xml includes the following dependancy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in mod1, I have defined in `src/test/java` an abstract test class

```
public abstract class ServicesAbstractTest {
...
}
```

in mod2, `src/test/java` I have defined a test class which inherits this one.

```
public class Mod2Test extends ServicesAbstractTest {
...
}
```

These are all Junit 4 tests. It works fine when I run the tests in Eclipse directly. But doesn't work when I do a `mvn clean install`, there are compilation errors showing that maven doesnt find `ServicesAbstractTest` when compiling and testing mod2.

I tried to apply what is said on similar questions : [Pascal Thivent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725476/maven-test-dependency-in-multi-module-project/1733745#1733745) and [Duncan Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722873/sharing-src-test-classes-between-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project) with 2 additional problems :

Strange

```
Could not find goal 'test-jar' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.2 among available goals test -> [Help 1]
```

And more compilation problems for module 2 : I think I need here to specify additionnal scope, not only test, I am going to do further research on this one.

Comment: The error message you're getting makes it sound like you tried to add the 'test-jar' goal to the configuration of the surefire plugin instead of the maven-jar-plugin which actually has that goal.

Comment: definitely it, thanks 1337joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1337joe 's comment is the one. [Pascal Thivent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725476/maven-test-dependency-in-multi-module-project/1733745#1733745) is what I was looking at.

Lessons learned

1. When finding a problem, begin to ask the question as precisely as
   possible. This is the best way to be pointed toward the most
   relevant answers to your problem. You might think you are loosing
   time in writing your question compare to a single google search with
   code error. You are actually finding faster the right answers
2. Dont be ashamed to look foolish when it happens that you just did a
   typo or equivalent : a second eye is always the best. It took probably 20 seconds to 1337joe to point out my plugin confusion that I could have spent hours on being too deeply involved in the problem.