# Sharing src/test classes with Maven without version specification for test-jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm sharing src/test classes between number of modules, in a similar way described in [attaching tests guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) and the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722873/sharing-src-test-classes-between-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project).

So, I have the following pom.xml dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**BUT**, in opposite to the question above, when attaching the test-jar, i don't want to specify the specific test-jar version. As in the compile level dependency:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In this case, my pom.xml become erroneous with message about the missing version. Why is this happen? Why i can specify **dependency without versions** but not the test-jar one? Is there a way to overcome this and make the test-jar to use the latest jar it can find?

Comment: Take a look at this answer to see if fits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Comment: Is this a multi module build?

Comment: @khmarbaise, yes, it's a multi module build.

Comment: @PauloSantos thanks, it's a good source. But my question is beyond that - I want to understand *why in the first place*, defining dependency without version don't work in my case (even if it's not a recommended practice).

Comment: Specifying dependencies without version won't work because maven was designed that way. But it works only for plugins, maven will use the latest version when you don't specify the plugin <version>. The only case *that I'm aware* that allow you use a dependency without version, is when you have the dependency already defined (with version) in a <dependecyManagement> tag

Comment: You can simply use `${project.version}` in those cases.

Comment: @khmarbaise it's a good idea, but, modules version could be different so it could cause a problem.

Comment: @PauloSantos, after further investigation that's exactly the reason for that! We have a "main pom", which automatically generates appropriate version for each dependency in <dependecyManagement> section. So, it's the reason i could do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the main code dependency could be used without the version, is the existence of a "main pom" in our project that automatically generates appropriate version for each dependency in  section. Therefore, each dependency can be specified without specific version number.

Test-jar dependency on the other hand, don't have it's version defined anywhere else in the transitive dependency so, the specific version must be specified.