# Failed to execute goal on project spark-core_2.11

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, jar

,
**Spark code compile operation fails on few machines whereas the same source code passes on few other machines.**
Please check the error on Centos (4.10.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64)
./build/mvn -X -DskipTests -Dscala.lib.directory=/usr/share/scala -pl core compile

```
INFO] Building Spark Project Core 2.2.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:tests:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.804 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-04T23:18:58-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/1963M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spark-core_2.11: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:tests:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT in http://artifact.eng.stellus.in:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

**Note: The same source code passes on another CentOS machine(3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64)**
./build/mvn -DskipTests -Dscala.lib.directory=/usr/share/scala -pl core compile

```
[INFO] — maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ spark-core_2.11 —
[INFO] Not compiling main sources
[INFO]
[INFO] — scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-core_2.11 —
[INFO] Using zinc server for incremental compilation
[info] Compile success at Dec 4, 2017 11:17:34 PM [0.331s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.663 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-04T23:17:34-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/1297M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where did you get `2.2.2-SNAPSHOT` from? I don't remember seeing it before.

Answer (score 0):

If the build works only in specific machine it means that you already have the missing dependency on your `.m2` local repository. 
If you will remove all your directories under `.m2` (on the centos machine) the build will fail.

You should add all your missing dependencies.

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:tests:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
In our case the repository was not empty but still the build was not working. Hence I copied the .m2/repository from the machine where the build had passed clean to the server on which it failed. After performing compile operation the build ran successfully after copying the .m2/repository.
Now my concern is what if I did not have any machine where the build had passed clean before and it as a very first attempt to perform compile operation on a newly installed server and I do not have any backup of .m2/repo from other servers how would I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following patch fix the compilation bug

```
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index cc48ee794e..ef0b01bec8 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -2518,6 +2518,13 @@
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.2</version>
+                 <executions>
+                   <execution>
+                     <goals>
+                       <goal>test-jar</goal>
+                     </goals>
+                   </execution>
+                 </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
```

See here stackoverflow.com/questions/4786881
[why is "test-jar" dependency required for "mvn compile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786881/why-is-test-jar-dependency-required-for-mvn-compile)

Another possibility:
you have a maven profile that does `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>` (which skips both test compilation and execution)
instead of 
`<skipTests>true</skipTests>`
(which skip execution, but compiles test)